# Extending YAML alias anchors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, yaml, rails-i18n, string-interpolation

I'm trying to construct dynamic YAML to return strings, I'm wondering if it is possible to do something like this with YAML?

```
en:
  occupation: "Studying #{department} at %{university} %{*speciality}"
  speciality: &speciality "specialising in %{subject}"
```

#### expected output

```
I18n.t(:occupation, :department => "Computer Science", 
                    :university => "Staffordshire University", 
                    :subject    => "Ruby")
#=> "Studying Computer Science at Staffordshire University specialising in Ruby"

I18n.t(:occupation, :department => "Computer Science", 
                    :university => "Staffordshire University", 
                    :subject    => nil)
#=> "Studying Computer Science at Staffordshire University"
```

Currently the only way I think this may be posible is

```
subject = "Ruby"
I18n.t(:occupation, :department => "Computer Science", 
                    :university => "Staffordshire University", 
                    :subject    => (
                      I18n.t(:speciality, :subject => subject) if subject
                    ))
#=> "Studying Computer Science at Staffordshire University specialising in Ruby"
```